# mist configuration file

Tags: mist

Does mist support reading default startup options from a configuration file?

[geth doesn't support configuration files](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/2067), so when starting mist, I need to pass:

```
--syncmode light --node-datadir "XDG_DATA_HOME/etherium"
```

I don't want to type this every time.

Does mist support a configuration file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems from [this issue](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/3071) that `mist` doesn't support a config file.